# Инициализация свойств контрола без перерисовки

Tags: c#, winforms, .net, visual-studio

Привет, Хэшкод!

Я создаю контрол, наследуясь от `UserControl`. К нему добавляю свойство, от которого зависит внешний вид контрола.

Теперь внимание, если присваивать это свойство в коде конструктора формы сразу после `InitializeComponent()`, то сначала пользователь увидит форму такой, как она выглядела у меня в режиме «дизайна мышкой», и уже после этого контрол перересуется в нужный мне вид. Плохо.

Пометить свойство с помощью `BrowsableAttribute` я тоже не могу, ибо тип свойства — мой собственный класс, настраивать который среда не умеет. Плохо.

Как же сделать так, чтобы инициализация свойства произошла между первыми `form1.SuspendLayout()` и `form1.ResumeLayout(false)?`

---

В идеале хотелось бы иметь возможность писать код, непосредственно в поля окошка «свойства». Например если свойство имеет тип `MyClass`, то в соответсвующее поле из окна «свойства» я бы написал `new MyClass(param1, param2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .Net есть возможность создания своих редакторов свойств контрола на основе `UITypeEditor`, что как раз даст возможность изменять свойство контрола через свой пользовательский интерфейс.

Ссылки по теме:

[Класс UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx)

[Статья: Creating Custom Controls - Providing Design Time Support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9667/Creating-Custom-Controls-Providing-Design-Time-Sup)

[Пошаговое руководство. Реализация редактора типов пользовательского интерфейса](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171840.aspx)